# Angularjs $resource - consume rest No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and building a demo app. I have some basic function working fine. It calls a rest service and will display on page with following.

```
  <div class="bio-graph-heading">
    {{profileUpdateResult.member[0].DESC_HEADLINE}}</div>
  <div class="panel-body profile-graph-info">
```

I am trying to walk thru the results from rest call with $resource. I am now seeing an error.

I need to set the dropdown options. I will walk thru the results and set the dropdowns with the following.

```
    <div class="row">

      <div class="profile-row">
        <label for="seekingArrayValueSel">Seeking a:</label>
        <select style="width:220px;"  id="seekingArrayValueSel" required="required"  ng-model="seekingArrayValue" ng-options="seeking.detail for seeking in seekingArray">
          <option style="display:none" value="">[Not selected]</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

in controller

```
 $scope.seekingArray = [
  {id: "1", code: "M", detail: "Man"},
  {id: "2", code: "F", detail: "Woman"}
];

scope.seekingArrayValue = $scope.seekingArray[1];
```

I would like to read thru the results and set the dropdowns with previous selected from profileMembersUpdateAPI call.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Phil

=========== controller code =====

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp');

  testApp.controller('ProfileUpCtrl', ['$scope','$location', '$resource','$modal',  function ($scope, $location, $resource, $modal) {

$scope.profileMembersUpdateAPI = $resource("http-link://test.dev:3000/auth/profileupdate", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, {get: {method: "JSONP"}});
$scope.profileUpdateResult = $scope.profileMembersUpdateAPI.get();

// profileUpdateResult.member[0].DESC_HEADLINE
 console.log($scope.profileUpdateResult);   // displays a valid result. 
$scope.myData = { memberList: []  };

$scope.setMemberList = function () {
  console.log('in setmember list');
  profileMembersUpdateAPI.query({
  }, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.myData.memberList = data;
  });
};

console.log('phil a -- >  ');
$scope.memberdata = $scope.setMemberList;
```

== error shown here from chrome developer inspector. ==

XMLHttpRequest cannot load link-http://test.dev:3000/auth/profileupdate?callback=JSON_CALLBACK. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: what do you use in the backend ? rails ?

Comment: back end is nodejs. It does return the results in JSON.           {
"memberupdate": [
{
"MEMBER_ID": 4890,
"MEMBER_AGE": 36,
"DESC_INTRO": " ",
"GENDER": "F",
"FIRST_NAME": "Jane",
"DESC_LOOKINGFOR": "Male",
"GENDER_SEEK": "M",

Comment: By default, you cannot make requests across different domains. So you cannot make a request from localhost:9000 to localhost:3000. This is something called CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), which -- for security reasons -- is not allowed by default. You need to explicitly enable CORS for this domain on your backend, i.e. your node.js server (you'll have to google "node.js CORS", because I am not familiar with node.js).

Comment: ok.. fixed that issue with   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next(); http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: It would be best if you write an answer to this question yourself so that others with the same issue can see an answer that helps them as well.

Comment: issued fixed.. thanks..